# Uncertainty in parenthesis

Tags: notation, error-analysis

In a physics text book I read the following:

> $$e/m=1.758820150(44) ×10^{11} \mathrm{C/kg} $$ 
>   In this expression, $(44)$ indicates the likely uncertainty in the last two digits, $50$.

How should I understand this uncertainty? Does it mean $\pm 44$ on the last two digits?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The digits in parentheses are the uncertainty, to the precision of the same number of least significant digits. (The meaning of the uncertainty is context-dependent but generally represents a standard deviation, or a 95% confidence interval.) So:
$$e/m=1.758\,820\,1\color{blue}{50}\,\color{magenta}{(44)}×10^{11} \ \mathrm{C/kg}=\left(1.758\,820\,1\color{blue}{50}×10^{11} \pm 0.000\,000\,0\color{magenta}{44}×10^{11}\right) \ \mathrm{C/kg}$$

Answer (score 1):

The uncertainty is equal to the **standard deviation** $\sigma = 0.000000044×10^{11} C/kg = 4400 C/kg$.  It means you are

- approx. 68% confident that the true value $m_e$ lies within the interval $[\hat m_e-\sigma, \hat m_e+\sigma]$, where $\hat m_e$ is the measure value.
- and approx. $95\%$ confident that the true value $m_e$ lies within the interval
  $[\hat m_e-2\sigma, \hat m_e+2\sigma]$.

Comment: Excuse me, but do you have any sources that use this kind of method and/or this notation? Sorry, it's just that I've only taken one statistics course and that was quite some time ago; although I know confidence intervals relatively well, I've never seen the math you've used before.